# How to POST NON-JSON request using Apache HttpClient?

Tags: java, json, httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am to hitting an API which will return string data and as well I want to send data of string type(textfile in a paragraph).

Comment: I want to use apache httpClient Asynchronously. In previous it was synchronous. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Apache httpcomponents, with http [entities](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/tutorial/html/fundamentals.html#d5e95)

Here is an example for sending a file in your POST request:

```
File file = new File("somefile.txt");
FileEntity entity = new FileEntity(file, ContentType.create("text/plain", "UTF-8"));        

HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://localhost/action.do");
httppost.setEntity(entity);
```

If you want a text content, you can use `StringEntity`:

```
StringEntity myEntity = new StringEntity("something", ContentType.create("text/plain", "UTF-8"));
```